# Embed Javascript into HTML: Mason for Perl

Tags: javascript, perl, mason

Is it possible to embed Javascript into HTML: Mason for Perl?

Thank you

```
<%init>
#do some perl code here

<script type="text/javascript">

//call some javascript function here

</script>
 #do some perl code here

</%init>
```

I have a web service exposed using JSON and I want to call it using Javascript code.

Can I put the Javascript code between <%perl>?

Comment: My reading of the manual suggests that `<%init>` is for Perl that should execute before anything else. I don't know why you would put JavaScript in there. JavaScript is content that needs to be output to the browser.

Comment: You can't put it in the `<%init>` section, because that's not what `<%init>` does. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a web service exposed using JSON and I want to call it using Javascript code.

Comment: Can I put the Javascript code between <%perl></%perl>?

Comment: Only if you were going to echo it out but why would … oh, I think I see…

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just put it in there.

HTML::Mason is designed to let you write ordinary HTML (including stylesheets, JavaScript, and anything else that's valid in a HTML document) while also allowing you to embed Perl code.

Comment: Can I do this in Mason? <%init>
#do some perl code here

<script type="text/javascript">

//call some javascript function here

</script>

</%init>

Comment: Ah if you're trying to execute JavaScript on the server side then you're either wanting Node.JS or you're very, very, very, very, very confused about web browsers and web servers.

Comment: I have a web service exposed using JSON and I want to call it using Javascript code.